# Add extra text in customer backend Address Book - Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2.4, shipping-address

we are using Magento 2.4.4.

Customers always get confused when they try to set a new shipping address.

They by the logic first need to add a new address and then only can select a different shipping address.

I would like to add an extra text therefore in the Address Book (and also add this extra text per store view and/or translate via the Theme or Core Locale)

It should look like this:

[image: Add extra text to Address Book]

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your requirement by following steps:

**Step 1:** Create **customer_address_index.xml** under your theme location like below:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_address_index.xml

Add the below code to your **customer_address_index.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" template="Dapl_OrderAttribute::html/title.phtml"/>
</page>
```

**Step 2:** Create **title.phtml** under your theme location like below:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_customer/templates/html/title.phtml

Add the below code to your **title.phtml**:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title
 */
$cssClass = $block->getCssClass() ? ' ' . $block->getCssClass() : '';
$titleHtml = '';
if (trim($block->getPageHeading())) {
    $titleHtml = '<span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" '
        . $block->getAddBaseAttribute()
        . '>'
        . $block->escapeHtml($block->getPageHeading())
        . '</span>';
}
?>
<?php if ($titleHtml) : ?>
<div class="page-title-wrapper<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($cssClass) ?>">
    <h1 class="page-title"
        <?php if ($block->getId()) : ?> id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getId()) ?>" <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($block->getAddBaseAttributeAria()) : ?>
            aria-labelledby="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddBaseAttributeAria()) ?>"
        <?php endif; ?>>
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $titleHtml ?>
        <div style="color:#ff0000; font-size: 14px;"><?= /* @noEscape */ __('To change the shipping address, please first add a new address and then select the new address') ?></div>
    </h1>    
    <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: Thank you @Sukumar. We will check and try and let you know the result.